# How to Publish web site on IIS with External IP Address via my computer

Tags: asp.net, iis

I can access the web site from the local network (192.168.2.120 My Local IP)
but i cant access the web site from global network (95.10.239.XXX My External IP)

- I opened 8080 port from the modem
- [IIS Edit Bindings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xb10.png)
- I opened 8080 port from firewall
- Im using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to check if port 8080 is accessible from outside. You can use this tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

**If it is accessible**, then it should work, if you will try to open in browser http://95.10.239.XXX:8080/

**If it is not accessible**, then you might need to do this steps:

1. Set up port forwarding and(or) DMZ in your router. It depends on your router.
2. Open firewall on your machine. You mentioned that you did that already.

Comment: Port is looks closed  http://prntscr.com/fihysu

Comment: Most probably you need to check your router settings